# How to generate a set of geospacial coordinates?

Tags: javascript

I tried using this:

```
function getRandomInRange(from, to, fixed) {
    return parseFloat((Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed));
}

var latLongPairs = 4;

for(var i =0; i<latLongPairs; i++) {
 console.log(`${getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)}, ${getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)}`);
}
```

That's ok for random numbers like `39.21988,9.124741` but they might end up not valid coordinates. And I need 100 of them.

Comment: The legal range for latitude is ±90, not ±180.   The Haversine formula is for calculating the great circle distance between two points on a sphere.

Comment: given their latitude and longitude, that is.   It's actually completely unclear what you're asking for.

Comment: @Alnitak I need to generate 100 valid random coords "longitude,latidude"

Comment: As pointed out above the range for latitude is ±90 but apart from that any combination will be valid, generate some pairs and if you plug them into Google Earth you'll see they all map to somewhere on Earth.

Comment: @PeterJ thing is that I did try that but some values were not recognised by google

Comment: @rob.m then you did it wrong.     Any lat/long pair in the range ±90 / ±180 should be fine.

Comment: @rob.m, Google Earth expects latitude,longitude format but probably the reason is you haven't restricted the latitude to -90, 90 in your first call to `getRandomInRange`.

Comment: @PeterJ not sure where I'd do that check, any example?

Comment: This is an example of your coords above: https://www.google.com/maps?q=39.21988,9.124741

Comment: @PeterJ yes, I might have pasted on here an actual working one lol, but some weren't working

Comment: @rob.m so fix your latitude range to ±90 like we've been saying and it'll be fine.   Your "fixed digit" handling is unnecessary btw, unless the intent is to allow routing to e.g. the nearest 10th of a degree.   `Number.toFixed` is intended for _displaying_ numbers with a particular precision, not rounding their actual values to 10ths, 100ths, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latitude range is incorrect - it should be ±90.

```js
function getRandomInRange(from, to) {
    return Math.random() * (to - from) + from;
}

const latLongPairs = 4;

for (let i = 0; i < latLongPairs; ++i) {
    let lat = getRandomInRange(-90, 90);
    let lon = getRandomInRange(-180, 180);
    console.log(`${lat.toFixed(3)}, ${lon.toFixed(3)}`);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! makes total sense

Answer (score -1):

You might need to provide some initial Latitude and longitude with some radius (in meters)

```js
var getRandomLocation = function(latitude, longitude, radiusInMeters) {

  var getRandomCoordinates = function(radius, uniform) {
    // Generate two random numbers
    var a = Math.random(),
      b = Math.random();

    // Flip for more uniformity.
    if (uniform) {
      if (b < a) {
        var c = b;
        b = a;
        a = c;
      }
    }

    // It's all triangles.
    return [
      b * radius * Math.cos(2 * Math.PI * a / b),
      b * radius * Math.sin(2 * Math.PI * a / b)
    ];
  };

  var randomCoordinates = getRandomCoordinates(radiusInMeters, true);

  // Earths radius in meters via WGS 84 model.
  var earth = 6378137;

  // Offsets in meters.
  var northOffset = randomCoordinates[0],
    eastOffset = randomCoordinates[1];

  // Offset coordinates in radians.
  var offsetLatitude = northOffset / earth,
    offsetLongitude = eastOffset / (earth * Math.cos(Math.PI * (latitude / 180)));



  return `${latitude + (offsetLatitude * (180 / Math.PI))}, ${longitude + (offsetLongitude * (180 / Math.PI))}`
};

for (i = 0; i < 182; i++) {
  console.log(getRandomLocation(41.8819, -87.6278, 50))
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. Why did they give you a down vote?

Comment: God knows why :P

Comment: because the code is opaque and doesn't appear to do what the OP asked.   IIUC, it's attempting to generate coordinates that are within a certain radius of a given lat/long, not anywhere on the globe.

Comment: in particular I have no idea whatsoever what you're attempting to do in the code that says it's trying to make the distribution "more uniform".

Comment: @Alnitak I need them anywhere in the world actually

Comment: @rob.m exactly, and this code does not do that.

Comment: @Alnitak correct, I can even see it by the coords results which are near a point

Comment: Can't we pass Earth's radius in the radius param?

Comment: @HarshitRastogi even if the math is correct (which I doubt, for larger values of `radius`) that would only allow for points that are on the hemisphere centered on that point.

Comment: @Alnitak that'll depend upon the initial values of latitude and longitude passed

Comment: @HarshitRastogi it's hard to tell, but the code looks like it generally assumes that the earth is flat in the immediate vicinity of the given point.